# HAML / Ruby - Code Helper Blocks

Tags: ruby, haml, padrino, middleman

I create something like this

Which produces a partial - creates the code elements and renders the code partial
I would like to wrap this all into one tidy element - ie calling the code partial will automatically render the partials inside the code block... so avoiding the replication

```
-# Text
= partial "./forms/input",
           :locals => { :name        => "text",
                        :label       => [ "Text Input" ],
                        :placeholder => "Enter Text",
                        :required    => true }

-# Code
:ruby
    code = %Q{
    partial "./forms/input",
               :locals => { :name        => "text",
                            :label       => [ "Text Input" ],
                            :placeholder => "Enter Text",
                            :required    => true }}

= partial "./scaffolding/code", :locals => { :code => code }
```

I thought it may be something like:

```
- haml_engine = Haml::Engine.new( code )
- output = haml_engine.render
- puts output
```

But I get undefined method `partial'

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Do you mean to use render instead of partial. I think the correct way to do is,
render partial: "scaffolding/code", locals: {code: code}

Comment: I use Middleman which in turn is Padrino - http://www.padrinorb.com/api/Padrino/Helpers/RenderHelpers.html so should be ok

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your goal rather than the implementation that you tried and found not usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the following is what I wanted.

```
-# Code
:ruby
    code = %{partial "./forms/input",
               :locals => { :name        => "text",
                            :label       => [ "Text Input" ],
                            :placeholder => "Enter Text",
                            :required    => true }}

= eval( code )

-# Code
:code
    #lang: #{ lang }
    = code
```